# How to align the legend of a figure correctly?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\checkmark" macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure~} % unbreakable space after fig. #
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
%Insere Figura
\caption{Figure Description}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{img/tex.png}
\legend{Source: (Blokland2013)}
\label{fig:testemultiplataforma}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Figure Description}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}  
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 1}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa1IF}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %\qquad
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 2}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa2IF}
    \end{subfigure}
    \legend{Source: Own authorship}
    \label{fig:DifExp2Per4IF}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In my original document there is the command `\legend{}`, but I have already looked in the `cls` file and in the imports of all my packages and I do not know where this command is coming from. What package is this command coming from?

How should I do to align the `legend` text to the left instead of centered according to the following figures?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where? At left, under the figure, or above ? On the left side, rotated?  Where should the main caption be? Under or above?

Comment: `\legend` is not a standard macro, so what is your question actually? Also, I don't think this is the standard method of adding source references to figures. Most recommendations I've seen include adding it ad the end of the (main) caption.

Comment: Hello @Bernard, the `caption` should be at the top of the figure with center alignment and the `legend` at the bottom with left alignment.

Comment: Hello @daleif, this is a recommendation of the standards of the Brazilian Association of Technical Standards (ABNT).

Comment: @ricardoramos oh no, not that one again. pas... Why are you not using the specific abnt class, I think there is a `abntex2` class on CTAN. That presumably implements this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i understand, you like use the legend as notice of image source. for this purpose has been developed package `copyrightbox`. by it you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\checkmark" macro
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}% <--- added

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure~} % unbreakable space after fig. #
%
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{% < ---for changing copyright font color/shape/family
\footnotesize
\color{black}% 
            }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Figure Description}
\label{fig:testemultiplataforma}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{img/tex.png}}{Source: Blokland2013}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Figure Description}
    \label{fig:DifExp2Per4IF}
\copyrightbox[b]{\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 1}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa1IF}
    \end{subfigure}\quad
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 2}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa2IF}
    \end{subfigure}}{Source: Own authorship}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
by defining new command `legend`:

```
\newcommand\legend[1]{%
    \captionsetup{font=small,singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption*{#1}}
```

you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\checkmark" macro
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\legend[1]{%
    \captionsetup{font=small,singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption*{#1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure~} % unbreakable space after fig. #
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Figure Description}
\label{fig:testemultiplataforma}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{img/tex.png}%}{Source: Blokland2013}
\legend{Source: Blokland2013}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Figure Description}
    \label{fig:DifExp2Per4IF}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 1}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa1IF}
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/tex.png}
            \caption{Figure 2}
            \label{fig:DifExp2Per4Tarefa2IF}
\end{subfigure}
\legend{Source: Own authorship}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Zarko, I edited my question and put two examples of formatted figures.  The `caption` should be at the top of the figure with center alignment and the `legend` at the bottom with left alignment.

Comment: @ricardoramos, i adopt may answer to edited question. maybe you liked it.

Comment: Hello @Zarko, how should I do to the text color of the
Source to be black instead of gray?

Comment: @ricardoramos, meanwhile i provide new solution. with defining `legend`

Comment: @ Hello Zarko, the other way you had done got better, just missed changing the font color of the Source for black instead of gray. https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/figure-png

Comment: @ricardoramos, i recover first version of answer and change copyright  font color as you ask. now you have two solutions in one answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with the `copyrightbox` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
\caption{Heinrich Füssli – The Nightmare (1781)}
        \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{Nightmare_Fussli}}{Detroit Institute of Arts}
    \end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Allowed placements use  an optional argument: `[l]`, `[r]` (default) or `[b]`